# FullCalendar Events not showing up only on Safari

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, safari, fullcalendar

I've been working with FullCalendar plugin for a bit now and I've managed to get it working in FF and Chrome but I can't seem to understand why the events don't show up on Safari.

I am using a Rails backend to fetch the events as an array. This is the JSON object for the events that FireBug displays.

```
_end: Invalid Date    
_id: "1953"   
_start: Fri Feb 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)  
allDay: false  
backgroundColor: "#F60 !important"  
className: Array[0]  
color: "#FFFFFF !important"  
description: ""  
end: Invalid Date  
start: Fri Feb 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)   
textColor: "#FFFFFF !important"   
__proto__: Object
```

I have no errors on the safari console. The invalid end date shows up as `null` on FF and Chrome.

Here is how I populate the events

```
event[:id]                        = each_event.id    
event[:title]                = each_event.event_title    
event[:allDay]               = each_event.all_day?   
event[:start]                = each_event.start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')    
event[:end] = each_event.end_date.to_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00') if each_event.end_date.present?          
event[:color]                = '#FFFFFF !important'      
event[:backgroundColor]      = (each_event.user ==  current_user) ? '#F60 !important' : '#090 !important'          
event[:backgroundColor]      = '#090 !important' unless each_event.private?       
event[:textColor]            = '#FFFFFF !important'
```

I tried converting the datetime to iso8601 format too and it did not work. I'm completely clueless on what the problem is. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: I've been using fullCalendar for a while now and up until this point all problems I encountered with Safari were the fact that dates are being parsed a bit differently. For instance, (Safari 6.0(7536.25) on Mac) -- new Date('01-01-2000') is invalid where as in other browsers it is perfectly valid. In these cases you should replace all hyphens with forward-slashes so the result is something like new Date('01/01/2000'). I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @TomReznik In my case, it was the strings, and this question led me to look in the right place. But it was not the dashes vs slashes issue, it works perfectly fine with dashes in my case. Instead it was the format of the day, I was outputting a single digit (2012-11-1) and the missing leading 0 is what was throwing it off. I would guess this error is encountered more often near the end of the year, I'm sure the month suffers from the same error, but it went unnoticed in October and November.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
What helped me was using the **.iso8601** function of DateTime:

```
event[:start] = each_event.start_time.iso8601
event[:end] = each_event.end_date.to_time.iso8601 if each_event.end_date.present?
```

iso8601 format gives output like: 2017-01-25T16:15:49+01:00

Comment: Old question, but this answer seems good. Changing from rfc822 to iso8601 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I switched my date format from:

"2019-05-09 04:00:00"

to

"2019-05-09T04:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Your string isn't in the right format.

Instead of using

```
event[:start] = each_event.start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')
event[:end] = each_event.end_date.to_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00') if each_event.end_date.present?
```

try to use

```
event[:start] = each_event.start_time.to_json
event[:end] = each_event.end_date.to_time.to_json if each_event.end_date.present?
```

According to FullCalendar documentation the start and end properties requires a Date object or a string in IETF format, ISO8601 format or a UNIX timestamp. Because `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')` is none of those, the code would not work.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/